# Why won't my script run?

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I've built the following PowerShell script and it doesn't seem to work:

```
"\\example\examplepath\" | % { $_ | select name, @{n="lines"; e={ get-content
$_.FullName | measure-object -line | Select -expand lines  }  } } | ft -
Autosize | Out-file c:\counts\result.csv
```

The script is supposed to get a line count for each file and output them to a CSV. Admittedly there around 140,000 files in the folder. Any ideas?

Comment: Just put a "GCI" before the first line of the script.

Answer (score 3):

You are *missing* the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet to retrieve all files. The `Foreach-Object` (`%`) cmdlet is obsolete here so I removed it. I also removed the `Format-Table` cmdlet because you are piping the result to `Out-File`:

```
Get-ChildItem "\\example\examplepath\" |
     Select-Object name, @{n="lines"; e={ get-content $_.FullName | measure-object -line | Select-Object -expand lines  }  } |
     Out-file c:\counts\result.csv
```